# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP: in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have a Login.jsp page.When I try to run it on server I get the following error:

```
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:


description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [1] in the generated java file: 

The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
```

What causes this error?

Comment: Improve formatting first! The question is unreadable!

Comment: I found the solution I changed from Apache 7 to Apache 8 now things are working fine !

Comment: Great! Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I changed from Apache 7 to Apache 8 now things are working fine !